# I want to change data type of joining_date field from varchar to datetime

Tags: mysql

In mysql-The table 'Employee' looks like as:

Joining_date
01-JAN-13 12.00.00 AM
01-JAN-13 12.00.00 AM
01-FEB-13 12.00.00 AM
01-FEB-13 12.00.00 AM
01-FEB-13 12.00.00 AM
01-JAN-13 12.00.00 AM
01-JAN-13 12.00.00 AM
01-FEB-13 12.00.00 AM

At the time of creation by mistaken I provided varchar data type for 'joining_date' instead of datetime.

Plz help in converting column 'joining_date'from varchar to datetime.

Comment: try using this "ALTER TABLE Employee
MODIFY Joining_date datetime"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.....

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype
```

or this...

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype
```